# Separation properties for the k-topology $\{(a,b): a<b; a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'd like to know the separation properties (is it Hausdorff, regular or normal) for the following bases.

Suppose $X$ is a topological space

(1) $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b):a<b; a,b \in R\}$

Hausdorff: if we take a point $a$ and $b,$ with $a < b$

there is a disjoint open set $[a,b)$ and $[b, b+1)$ such that $a \in [a,b) $and $b\in [b, b+1).$

Since their intersection is empty, then it is Hausdorff.

Regular: If $a \in X$ and $A$ is closed subset of $X$ with $a \notin A,$

there exist an open set $[a,b)$ with $[a,b) \subset (X \setminus A)$

then $[a,b)$ and $X\setminus[a,b)$ are disjoint open set with $a \in [a,b)$ and $A \subset X\setminus[a,b)$

therefore $X$ is regular.

Normal: Let a,b $\in R$, with a < b, there is c $\in R$ such that a < c < b

Let A and B be disjoint closed set in X with a $\in$ A and b $\in$ B

a $\in$ A = [a,c) and b $\in$ B = [c, b+1)

[a,c) $\cap$ [c, b+1) is empty.

There exist open sets

U = $\cup$ [a,c) for a $\in$ A

and V = $\cup$ [c,b+1) for b $\in$ B

which are disjoint with A $\subset$ U and B $\subset$ V.

Hence X is normal.

(2) $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b): a<b; a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

(3) $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,\infty): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Please Is (1) correct? Anyone can help on (2) and (3)

Answer (score 1):

You're fine for Hausdorffness for (1). Regularity and normality require a bit more work.

(2) is the usual topology, which is metrisable, so all mentioned separattion axioms follow from that.

(3) will fail Hausdorffness, as all non-empty open sets intersect. For similar reasons regularity will fail. Are there even disjoint non-empty closed sets to test normality?

Comment: Can you complete the missing part for (1).

Comment: I have attempted the normality for (1). Am I on right track?

Comment: @NiangMoore no, you have a long way to go yet, with regularity also.

Comment: Any hint on what I'm missing out

Comment: @NiangMoore for normality of (1) see [this blog post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/), e.g.